# How to add separate rails model into an active_admin form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have an active_admin form for ProspectReview as so:

```
ActiveAdmin.register ProspectReview do

  permit_params :domain, :media_type, :is_prospect, :category, :corrected_domain, :source, :share, :collection, :api_lookup_at

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "ProspectReview" do
      f.input :domain
      f.input :media_type, :as => :select, :collection => ["website","facebook","twitter","blogspot","tumblr","instagram","klout","pinterest","google+","linkedin","youtube","blog","mobile app","lookbook","bloglovin"]
      f.input :is_prospect, :as => :select, :collection => ["yes", "no"]
      f.input :category, :as => :select, :collection => []
      f.input :corrected_domain
      f.input :source
      f.input :share
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

I have a table called main_topics with an attribute of name:

```
create_table "main_topics", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name", limit: 255
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

My goal is to add the attribute name from **main_topics** into the **ProspectReview ActivAdmin** form where the category selection dropdown is:

```
f.input :category, :as => :select, :collection => []
```

That way anytime the table **main_topics** is updated with a new row. Whatever is in the name column will populate inside the dropdown selection.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple. I was getting an error for

```
f.input :category, :as => :select, :collection => [MainTopic.all]
```

I needed to remove the [] around MainTopic.all.